# jQuery css() triggering animation unexpectedly

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I want a div to slide down top `top:0` but I don't know its height. So I use jQuery to get its height while it's not displayed, then move it to `(0-height)` before adding the class `open` which will animate it down into view.

**CSS**

```
.settings-dropdown
{
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    padding:5% 2%;
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:    all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:     all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:      all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    transition:         all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
.settings-dropdown.open
{
    display:block;
    top:0;
}
```

**JS**

```
var height = $('div.settings-dropdown').outerHeight();
$('div.settings-dropdown').css({'height':height,'top':(0-height)}).addClass('open');
```

Problem is, `jQuery.css()` is triggering the animation when I use it to define the `top` position. So I either have to wait 0.8 seconds to add the `open` class, or ... what, exactly?

Comment: where is your html ?

Comment: The html is irrelevant.

Comment: how could we verify what you are saying ??

Comment: create a div with the class "settings-dropdown" and put any content in it you want. That's how.

Comment: In orderto determine the size of a hidden element, jQuery has to make it visible temporarily so the browser will calculate the dimensions. Normally this isn't visible to the user because nothing is rendered until jQuery finishes. But if you have transitions enabled, it triggers the animation to and from those states.

Comment: OK, so how do I achieve what I'm trying to achieve (dynamically add the top position based on the unknown height, without triggering the animation)?

Comment: By the way, Barmar, the animation isn't being triggered by the `outerHeight()` call. It's triggered by the `css({'top'})` call. Verified using alerts to stop the flow of each action.

Comment: @Thom Why do you need to know the height of the div? Why not just start its position somewhere in the negative realm and just transition to 0 using the open class? By the way, moving the div with `transform` will yield better results than modifying the `top` property.

Comment: also don't forget that specifying property with jQuery will be inline CSS, so the top:0 of open class has no effect here

Comment: @AndyHoffman, because I want the transition to be visible at 0.1 seconds, not 0.6 of 0.8. 

I should just use jQuery.animate().